# Multiline NSTokenField and the return key

Tags: cocoa, multiline, nstextfield, nstokenfield

I have a `NSTokenField` object with multilines (just resized the control vertically in interface builder). Unfortunately the `NSTokenField` object does not insert new line when pressing the return key. Any ideas how to make the control insterting a new line when pressing the return key?

Do I really have to go the complicated way through delegates like  `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By default, text fields (and by extension token fields) do not insert a new line when pressing the return key. This is the expected behavior.

A user who wishes to enter a return instead of tokenizing or committing the input may press Option-Return.

If you wish to disable this behavior programatically (be careful not to break the user's expectations) then the delegate is by far the easiest way to do so.

Comment: imo the user expectation is inserting a new line when pressing the return key if the text field has more then one line. The multi line label listed in the IB palette (which is new in IB 3.0) inserts indeed a new line when pressing the return key.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no other simpler way.
But it is not too complicated anyway - here the swift code to use in the delegate, so that enter and tab presses actually insert new lines and tabs :

```swift
 func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool
    {
        if (commandSelector == #selector(insertNewline))
        {
            textView.insertText("\n", replacementRange: textView.selectedRange)
            return true
        }
        else if (commandSelector == #selector(insertTab))
        {
            textView.insertText("\t", replacementRange: textView.selectedRange)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```